# Public key problem when installing ovirt on aws

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, ovirt

I started an instance on AWS with centos 6.4. I ran the following two commands:

```
$ yum localinstall http://resources.ovirt.org/releases/ovirt-release.noarch.rpm
$ yum -y install ovirt-engine
```

I got the following messages:

> warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
>
> Public key for python-websockify-0.5.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm is not installed

How can I solve this public key problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running a `yum update` first. The `ovirt-release.noarch.rpm` did not include a RPM key and it's now complaining that there is no signing key available in your RPM configuration that can be used to verify the authenticity of the `python-websockify-0.5.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm` RPM.

Poking around the ovirt website, I did find this page titled: [oVirt Deployment Options](http://www.ovirt.org/Download). It discusses that the RPMs are signed, which is a good thing.

> #### GPG Keys used by oVirt
>
> Important: We are going to sign RPMs only from next release. Please wait for the announcement email

For starters I would attempt to do this first, to see if you can get `yum` to do the heavy lifting and install the RPM keys for ovirt.

```
$ sudo yum install ovirt-release
```

If that doesn't resolve things then you'll likely need to follow the directions from the link above which has full details for importing the keys manually into your RPM installation using `gpg`.

If you'd just like to get past this whole thing you can of course tell `yum` to disregard checking the origins of the packages like so:

```
$ yum -y --nogpgcheck install ovirt-engine
```